# How to remove horizontal line of endnotes in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010

It is possible in [Word 2003](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/change-or-remove-a-footnote-or-endnote-separator-HP005186236.aspx) and [Word 2007](http://compdocjos.blogspot.hu/2010/10/change-or-remove-horizontal-line-above.html). How can it be done in Word 2010?

Comment: I just tried this, and in Word 2010 it seems to be the same as in the link you have posted for Word 2007. So when you try to follow the steps in your Word 2007, where does it go wrong for you?

Comment: You are right, I wasn't in the correct view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are in *Draft view* before following the same steps at those under Microsoft Word 2007.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Select the text before or after the line at the end notes

Go to Format menu, select borders and shading .

Check   "Apply to:" menu from lower right corner , if it's parahgraph select text --- if its text then select paragraph
Click OK -( the line should be removed)

if it dsnt, select the entire document and repeat the process

image source : [wikihow](https://superuser.com/questions/650542/how-to-remove-horizontal-line-of-endnotes-in-word-2010)

Comment: It is not applicable for my case as there are no borders involved.